# content overlapping when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, overlapping

I am very new to coding and literally have no idea how to fix this and would really appreciate some help.

I'm creating a virtual cv; have some content that keeps on overlapping when the browser is resized and nothing I try will stop it...

I want the content to resize as the broswer resizes; if possible. But I do not want the content to overlap..

my work so far is hosted on codepen; here's the link...

*this is my work* http://codepen.io/JRMatthews/pen/RKWjLa

`<div class='title'>
  <p>Jordan Matthews</p>
  </div>`

That title is seemingly overlapping the writing that is below it; but I want it to stay above and not overlap; just like when the browser is full size...

please help

*****EDIT****

I also would really appreciate finding out the easiest way to centre align all of my content- as I can't seem to work out how to do it.

but the biggest issue is with the overlapping.

I can add screenshots if needed but the link to my pen on CodePen has been inserted.

PLEASE HELP. THANKS.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning on everything like that if you want the content to scale with the browser. Just write HTML and CSS that flows with the DOM. Unfortunately, this requires a decent understanding of CSS. If you're just interested in making a cv and not learning how CSS works, you might look at a CSS framework like Bootstrap or others, or even find a pre-made template online. And re: centering stuff, this is a good resource https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: You need to learn more about how to use CSS, and do a lot more research. You're supposed to ask a question on this site only *after you have exhausted all other resources*, not as soon as you get stuck on a beginner problem.

Comment: I have researched but can't find anything that actually works.. I have saw other posts that suggest things but once I try that on my code, it doesn't seem to work.. - nothing I do seems to stop the title 'Jordan Matthews' from overlapping the writing below and it's really bugging me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove absolute positioning from your elements, there are plenty ways of positioning elements exactly where you want them to be, without using position absolute.

You can use `text-align` or `padding` and `margin` to change text position.

Remove all occurences of `position: absolute` from your CSS code.

Comment: thank you. - now I just need to position my text vertically so that I can complete this page and go to sleep lol

Comment: Your welcome! Try to play with text-align and margin or paddings if required.